# Finding closest coordinates in an array?

Tags: java, math, 2d, trigonometry

I have two ArrayList, Double data type, 
1.latitudes
2. longitudes,
each has over 200 elements

say i give a random test coordinates, say (1.33, 103.4), the format is [latitude, longitude]

is there any algorithm to easily find closest point,
or do i have to brute force calculate every possible point, find hypotenuse, and then compare over 200 hypotenuses to return the closest point? thanks

Comment: If you do calculate all hypotenuses, you can calculate distance and implement min(distance) logic all in one loop.  Also all your points should be geographically close to each other so you can consider this area a plain, otherwise you need to take into account Earth curvature.

Comment: what's your definition of distance? "hypothenuse" is a term from planar geometry, but your use of "longitude" and "latitude" seems to indicate the points are on the surface of a sphere ...

Comment: Have you looked at R-trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)? Or spatial indexing algorithms in general (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_index)?

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array of points along one axis. Then, locate the point in the array closest to the required point along this axis and calculate the distance (using whatever metric is appropriate to the problem topology and scale).

Then, search along the array in both directions until the distance to these points is greater than the best result so far. The shortest distance point is the answer.

This can result in having to search the entire array, and is a form of [Branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) constrained by the geometry of the problem. If the points are reasonably evenly distributed around the point you are searching for, then the scan will not require many trials.

Alternate spatial indices (like quad-trees) will give better results, but your small number of points would make the setup cost in preparing the index much larger than a simple sort. You will need to track the position changes caused by the sort as your other array will not be sorted the same way. If you change the data into a single array of points, then the sort will reorder entire points at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are sorted, you can use binary search to find a position of a requested point in array. After you find index, you should check four near by points to find the closest.

1)Suppose you have two sorted arrays longitudes-wise and latitudes-wise

2)You search first one and find two nearby points

3)Then you search second one and find two more points

4)Now you have from two to four points(results might intersect)

5)These points will form a square around destination point

6)Find the closest point

Answer (score 0):

it's not true that closest lat (or long) value should be choosen to search over the long (or lat) axis, in fact you could stay on a lat (or long) line but far away along the long (or lat) value

[image: worng approach]

so best way is to calculate all distances and sort them

Comment: The approach to select the closest point along one axis is a starting point for the search. It at least minimises the distance along one axis. Subsequent probes further away (in both directions) will identify the closest point. The choice of distance metric depends on the curvature of the area being considered.